# Is Cognos sql a query language? Is it an alternative to mysql or sql server?

Tags: sql, cognos

What kind of SQL is Cognos sql? Is it an alternative to mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [IBM docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRL5J_1.0.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.10.1.1.doc/c_cognos_sql.html):

> By default, IBM® Cognos® Framework Manager uses Cognos SQL to create
>   and edit query subjects. **Cognos SQL adheres to SQL standards and works
>   with all relational and tabular data sources.** Framework Manager
>   generates the most optimized SQL possible. In this way, Cognos SQL is
>   preferable.
>
> .....
>
> If the data source supports it, you can use the With clause with Cognos SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Cognos is quite visual but you're right can produce SQL and needs some SQL knowledge to set up as well as database knowledge.

Cognos can output it's reports into SQL and that code will run fine in a SQL query window. Even though it does look very odd and nothing like standard SQL code.

Taking code from a report is pretty simple...

Open Report Studio - Tools - Show Generated SQL/MDX

From Query Studio (usually designed by end users)...

Run in XML format - Click on the pen drop down (top right) open in report studio and follow the above directions.

Hope that helps some what.

We recently moved from Cognos to SSRS. Given my experience of both, let me know if you need a hand moving. SSRS for the win.